# JQuery: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery

I have this code and works well;

```
            $(".campodigitavel").change(function(){
                $(".campocalculado").each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr("ordem") == 1){ // O valor do primeiro item do grupo será o campo base para o cálculo.
                        lnTotal = $(this).val();
                    }
                    // Percorre todos os filhos cujo pai é o atual da iteração
                    $("[pai=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").each(function(){
                        if(this.value != ""){
                            lnTotal = eval(lnTotal + "" + $(this).attr("operador") + "" +  parseFloat(this.value));
                        }
                    });
                    $("#" + $(this).attr("target")).val(lnTotal);
                });
            });
```

But, when I alter the code adding the a function call like this:

```
$(".campodigitavel").change(function(){
                $(".campocalculado").each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr("ordem") == 1){ // O valor do primeiro item do grupo será o campo base para o cálculo.
                        lnTotal = $(this).val();
                    }
                    // Percorre todos os filhos cujo pai é o atual da iteração
                    $("[pai=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").each(function(){
                        if(this.value != ""){
                            lnTotal = eval(lnTotal + "" + $(this).attr("operador") + "" +  parseFloat(this.value));
                        }
                    });
                    $("#" + $(this).attr("target")).val(lnTotal);
                });
                calcularPercentual();
            });
```

The function code:

```
function calcularPercentual(){
            var lnValorReferencia, lnValorPai 

            lnValorReferencia = $("[percentual=true]").val();

            $('.perccalculado').each(function(){
                lnValorPai = $("#" + $(this).attr("pai")).val();
                if(lnValorPai != ""){
                    $(this).val(lnValorPai * 100 / lnValorReferencia);
                }
            });
        }
```

When the JQuery Code execute in second time, appear the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

Why?

Thanks,
Luciano

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the objects matching the '.perccalculado' selector (those with 'perccalculado' as the class)?

Comment: `<input type="text" id="delegadoperc" size="5" class="perccalculado" pai="delegado" readonly>
<input type="text" id="presidenteperc" size="5" class="perccalculado" pai="presidente" readonly>
<input type="text" id="hsperc" size="5" class="perccalculado" pai="hs" readonly>`

A total of 11 fields.

Comment: The entire code is here https://gist.github.com/1539856

Comment: The complete error in console of Crhome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
(anonymous function)TelaFixacaoMetas.html:56
e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
(anonymous function)TelaFixacaoMetas.html:54
e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
(anonymous function)TelaFixacaoMetas.html:49
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i`

Answer (score 2):

add (;) after `var lnValorReferencia, lnValorPai;`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot semicolon (`;`) after initializing var lnValorReferencia, lnValorPai

Answer (score 1):

I discover the erro after read this topic ( http://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-uncaught-syntaxerror) I open the page in firefox and it show me the true error.

I changed the name of atribute pai to paiperc on the fields with class="perccalculado".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting a semi-colon after the line:

```
var lnValorReferencia, lnValorPai
```

I'm kinda doubtful on this since js does a lot of implicit semicolon insertion, but worth a try